# Extracting n-th element of a mysqli query result

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, mysqli

With the old `mysql_` syntax I was able to do something like this:

```
$query=mysql_query('select id from rank');
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
$id0[$i] = mysql_result($query, $i, "id");
$id1[$i] = mysql_result($query, $i+1, "id");
$id2[$i] = mysql_result($query, $i+2, "id");  }
```

I'm finding a lot of difficulties in reaching the same result with `mysqli`; usually I fetch the data of a mysqli query using the function `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)` to extract recursively row by row all the records in the query result.

How can I obtain the result I need, i.e. extracting at each cycle of the recursive function the nth, nth+1, nth+2 element of the query result? And how can I refer to the nth element of the very `id` field? It seems impossible to me working with one row of the query result at a time...

Excuse me if this question appears to be silly, but I'm in the process of converting an old site made with the `mysql_` syntax into `mysqli_` and I'm encountering many difficulties even if i try to refer to PHP.net documentation (and of course to Stack Overflow knowledge...)...

**EDIT (PROBLEM SOLVED)**:
I've solved my problem following Jeroen's suggestions: being not available the `fetch_all` function, I created an array storing each row of the msqli query result through a loop:

```
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
    $table[]=$row;
```

Operating this way it's much easier pointing to each record of the table using the usual indexes:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $id0[$i]=$table[$i]["id"];
    $id1[$i]=$table[$i+1]["id"];
    $id2[$i]=$table[$i+2]["id"]; }
```

Comment: If you are converting the site anyway, I would suggest using the PDO class. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: @JakeParis: Just fyi he's looking for a mysqli_ solution. He just said he WAS using the mysql_ before, but he wants to achieve the same thing in mysqli.

Comment: @TiborB., See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-fetch.php

Comment: It seems there is a lot of people who answers the questions just before having read them... I don't think this behaviour is really useful to the community and to someone who is trying to solve a poroblem...

Comment: I think you're looking for [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://uk3.php.net/mysqli_fetch_all)? As in `$results[$i]['id']`?

Comment: I get this error "Call to undefined function" tryng to use mysqli_fetch_all() function. I'm using PHP version 5.3 Extra (or at least it's what my web provider declares...)

Comment: Don't know of any versions called `5.3 Extra` :-) But you can use `phpinfo();` to get the exact details of your php version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`mysqli_data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to set the result pointer to an arbitrary row in your result set.

So your code would look something like:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
  mysqli_data_seek($result, $i);
  // depending on your php version you might need a temporary variable to
  // get the ID
  $id0[$i] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['id'];
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this kind of approach, I think this is the right way to proceed (or, at least, the one which can solve my problem)

Comment: @Hunter It does what your old solution does. However, if you do this a lot - `$max` is large - it might be more efficient to get all rows from the query in an array in one go and get the results in your loop from that array.

Comment: what do you mean with "in one go"? Using a loop and storing each row fetched `mysqli_fetch_assoc` in an array... or using an appropriate function to get all data (really) in one go? Is the `fetch_all()` function you're referring to? Ah, it seems my PHP version is 5.3.1 (don't know what they meant with that "extra" ;-) ), so I wonder why I get that error with `fetch_all`.

Comment: @Hunter Yes, if `fetch_all()` is not available, I would loop once to get all results and store them in an array. You could end up getting all results as much as 3 times with what you have now. And having it all in an array would remove the need for a temporary variable to access the `id` key.

Comment: `fetch_all` is "Available only with mysqlnd": this seems to be the issue with my provider (altervista.org)... Btw I'll try to follow your last suggestion